# Prob. 2 (e), Sec. 27, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Open supersets and $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of closed noncompact sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This question concerns exercise 2(e) from section 27 (p.177) in Munkres' *Topology*:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $X$.
>
> - For any point $x \in X$, we define $$d(x, A) := \inf \{ \ d(x,a) \ \colon \ a \in A \ \}.$$
> - For $\epsilon > 0$ we define the *$\epsilon$-neighbourhood* of $A$ in $X$ to be the set $$U (A,\epsilon) := \{ \, x \in X \, : \, d(x,A) < \epsilon \, \}.$$
>
> ---
>
> - (d) Assume that $A$ is compact; let $U$ be an open set containing $A$. Show that some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ is contained in $U$.
> - (e) Show the result in (d) need not hold if $A$ is closed but not compact.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939244/prob-2-d-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-if-a-is-compact-and-u-is) is a Math Stack Exchange post of mine on Part (d).

**My effort:**

> Consider the set $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. Then $\mathbb{N}$ is closed, but not bounded and hence not compact.
>
> Let the set $U$ be given by 
>   $$U \colon= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( n - \frac{1}{2n}, n + \frac{1}{2n} \right). \tag{Definition 1 } $$
>
> This set $U$ is an open set containing $\mathbb{N}$.  We also note that set $U$ is a union of *disjoint* open intervals.
>
> Now let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number.
>
> Let us first choose $\epsilon$ such that 
>   $$ 0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{2} . $$ 
>   Then by Part (c) of this problem, we can show that 
>   $$ U(\mathbb{N}, \epsilon) = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (n-\epsilon, n+\epsilon). \tag{2}$$
>
> And so we have 
>   $$ U(\mathbb{N}, \epsilon)  \not\subseteqq U. \tag{3} $$
>   To see why , let us choose a natural number $N$ such that 
>   $$ N > \frac{1}{2\epsilon}. $$ 
>   Then 
>   $$ \epsilon > \frac{1}{2N}, $$ 
>   and if $r$ is any real number such that
>   $$ \epsilon > r > \frac{1}{2N}, $$
>   then we find that the real number $N + r$, for example, satisfies
>   $$ N+r \in \{ N- \epsilon, N + \epsilon \} \setminus \left( N - \frac{1}{2N}, N + \frac{1}{2N} \right), $$
>   and so the open interval $\left( N-\epsilon, N+\epsilon \right)$ is not contained in  the open interval $\left( N - \frac{1}{2N}, N+\frac{1}{2N} \right)$, that is, 
>   $$ ( N- \epsilon, N + \epsilon ) \not\subset \left( N - \frac{1}{2N}, N + \frac{1}{2N} \right); $$
>   moreover as the latter open interval $\left( N - \frac{1}{2N}, N + \frac{1}{2N} \right)$ is the only one of the *disjoint* open intervals in set $U$ that has a point in common with the former open interval $( N- \epsilon, N + \epsilon )$ [Please refer to (Definition 1) above.], so we can conclude that 
>   $$ (N - \epsilon, N + \epsilon) \not\subset U, $$
>   and since the open interval $\left( N-\epsilon, N+\epsilon \right)$ is contained in $U(\mathbb{N}, \epsilon)$ by virtue of (2) above, we can conclude that (3) does indeed hold.
>
> Now for any real  $\epsilon > 0$, we can a choose a real number $\delta$ such that 
>   $$ 0 < \delta < \min \left\{ \ \epsilon, \ \frac{1}{2} \ \right\}. $$
>   Then 
>   $$ U ( \mathbb{N}, \epsilon ) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \big( n-\epsilon, n+\epsilon \big) \supset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \big( n-\delta, n+\delta \big) = U( \mathbb{N}, \delta ). $$
>   That is,
>   $$U ( \mathbb{N}, \epsilon ) \supset   U( \mathbb{N}, \delta ). \tag{4} $$
>   Note that $0 < \delta < \frac{1}{2}$.
>   And, by (3) as 
>   $$ U(\mathbb{N}, \delta) \not\subseteqq U, $$
>   so we can also conclude that $$ U( \mathbb{N}, \epsilon ) \not\subseteqq U $$
>   either.

Is this example a suitable one?

Comment: Your question contained _a lot_ of stuff that wasn't really relevant to the specific question you were asking. Please try to make your questions concise. (No need to even mention every part of a multi-part question if you are only going to ask about one part.)

Comment: @user642796 thank you for your comment, but I've only included Part (d) in addition to Part (e), and that too only for reference. You see, this particular problem has FIVE parts!

Comment: @user642796 can you please have a look at my post now? I've just added some more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is fine. Another simple one, which I think allows to visualize what happens, is as follows: let $A=\{(x,0)| x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ the real line embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then let $$U := \{(x,y)|   |y|< \frac{1}{|x|}\}$$ (with the convention $1/0 := \infty$) the region between the graphs of $\pm 1/x$. The graph of $1/x$ approaches $A$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, so that no neighbourhood of $A$ with diameter bounded from below will fit into it.

Comment: your using the convention $1/0 \colon= \infty$ makes your argument appear to be not rigorous enough. Don't you think so? So can you please modify your argument to just avoid using any such thing.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood I just means that for $x=0$ there is no restriction for $y$, i.e. $(0, y)\in U $ for every $y$. I do not see what's not rigourous about that.

Comment: can you review my post again after I've edited it to include some more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your example is nice. (If $0\notin\mathbb N$.)

Comment: could you please take time going through my post once again? I've tried to be more thorough in my explanation.