# Prob. 2 (d), Sec. 27, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: If $A$ is compact and $U$ is an open set containing $A$, then . . .

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

Here is Prob. 2, Sec. 27, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$; let $A \subset X$ be nonempty.
>
> (a) Show that $d(x, A) = 0$ if and only if $x \in \overline{A}$.
>
> (b) Show that if $A$ is compact, $d(x, A) = d(x, a)$ for some $a \in A$.
>
> (c) Define the *$\epsilon$-neighborhood* of $A$ in $X$ to be the set 
>   $$ U(A, \epsilon) = \{ \ x \in X \ \vert \ d(x, A) < \epsilon \ \}. $$
>   Show that $U(A, \epsilon)$ equals the union of the open balls $B_d(a, \epsilon)$ for $a \in A$.
>
> (d) Assume that $A$ is compact; let $U$ be an open set containing $A$. Show that some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ is contained in $U$.
>
> (e) Show the result in (d) need not hold if $A$ is closed but not compact.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061985/prob-2-d-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-open-supersets-and-%cf%b5-neighbor) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350309/prob-2-e-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-open-supersets-and-epsilon) are two Math SE posts on this problem. And, [here](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-27-compact-subspaces-of-the-real-line/problem-2-solution/) is also a solution to this problem.

I think I'm clear on parts (a) through (c) of this problem. So here I'll give my attempt at part (d).

My Attempt:

> First, some notation:
>
> For any point $x \in X$, we define
>   $$ d(x, A)  \colon= \inf \{ \ d(x, a) \ \vert \ a \in A \ \}. \tag{Definition A} $$
>   And, for any point $p \in X$ and for any real number $\delta > 0$, we define 
>   $$ B_d (p, \delta) \colon= \{ \ x \in X \ \vert \ d(x, p) < \delta \ \}. \tag{Definition B} $$
>
> As $U$ is an open set in $X$ with the metric topology determined by the metric $d$, so, for every element $u \in U$, there exists a real number $\epsilon_u > 0$ such that 
>   $$ B_d \left( u, \epsilon_u \right) \subset U. $$
>   [Refer to Sec. 20 in Munkres, especially the portion of the section preceding Example 1.]
>
> In particular, as $A \subset U$, so, for every element $a \in A$, we can find a real number $\epsilon_a > 0$ such that 
>   $$ B_d \left( a, \epsilon_a \right) \subset U. \tag{1} $$
>   For each such $\epsilon_a > 0$, let us choose a real number $\delta_a$ such that 
>   $$ 0 < \delta_a \leq \frac{\epsilon_a}{2}. \tag{2} $$
>
> Now let us consider the collection 
>   $$ \left\{ \ B_d \left( a, \delta_a \right) \ \vert \ a \in A \ \right\}. $$
>   This is a collection of open sets of $X$ whose union contains the set $A$; that is, this collection is a covering of $A$ by sets open in $X$. So, by Lemma 26.1 in Munkres, there is some finite sub-collection of this collection that also covers $A$. That is, there exist points $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$ such that 
>   $$ A \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n B_d \left( a_j, \delta_{a_j} \right). \tag{3} $$
>
> Let us now put
>   $$ \epsilon \colon= \frac{1}{2} \min \left\{ \ \delta_{a_1}, \ldots, \delta_{a_n} \ \right\}. \tag{4} $$
>   This $\epsilon > 0$ of course, by virtue of (2) above.
>
> Now from Part(c)  we have 
>   $$ U (A, \epsilon) = \bigcup_{a \in A} B_d(a, \epsilon). $$
>   Let us pick an arbitrary point $x$ in $U(A, \epsilon)$. Then as 
>   $$ x \in \bigcup_{a \in A} B_d(a, \epsilon), $$
>   so by the definition of the union of sets there exists a point $a_* \in A$ such that 
>   $$ x \in B_d \left( a_*, \epsilon \right), $$
>   that is such that
>   $$ d \left( x, a_* \right) < \epsilon, \tag{5} $$
>   by virtue of (Definition B) above.
>
> Now as $a_* \in A$, so by virtue of (3) above, we can conclude that 
>   $$ a_* \in B_d \left( a_k, \delta_{a_k} \right) $$
>   and so 
>   $$ d \left( a_*, a_k \right) < \delta_{a_k}, \tag{6} $$
>   for *at least one* $k = 1, \ldots, n$. 
>   And for this same $k$, using (2), (4), (5), and (6) above, we obtain 
>   $$ 
> d \left( x, a_k \right) \leq d \left(x, a_* \right) + d \left( a_*, a_k \right) < \epsilon + \delta_{a_k} < \delta_{a_k} + \delta_{a_k} = 2 \delta_{a_k} \leq \epsilon_{a_k}.  $$
>   Thus 
>   $$ x \in B_d \left( a_k, \epsilon_{a_k} \right). $$
>   So from (1) we conclude that $x \in U$.
>
> But by our choice $x$ was an arbitrary element of $U(A, \epsilon)$. Therefore we have 
>   $$ U(A, \epsilon ) \subset U. $$

Is this proof correct? If so, then is each and every step of this proof clear enough too? If not, then where is it lacking?

Comment: I think there is no problem.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Looks good. For (e) let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Let $A=\Bbb N$ and $U=\cup\{ (-2^{-n}+n,\,2^{-n}+n): n\in \Bbb N\}.$

Comment: In my previous comment I should have said: Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual metric (i.e. $ d(x,y)=|x-y|$.)

Comment: I would prefer $\delta_a =\frac{\epsilon_a} {2}$ in place of inequality. $\epsilon =\min \{ \delta_{a_1},…., \delta_{a_n}\}$ also works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite detailed and seems correct to me.

Another approach: $f:x \to d(x,X\setminus U)$ is continuous.
As $A \subseteq U$ and $X\setminus U$ is closed, we know that $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in A$.
By compactness $\min f[A]$ exists. Let $\varepsilon = \min f[A]>0$.

Then a small argumentation will show that this $\varepsilon$ is as required. (I believe your second linked answer also follows this approach). I believe the continuous distance argument is actually better and builds on stuff that's already been shown so is not more complicated. The whole point of having a body of such results is to make for more convenient proofs later, instead of reducing all compactness proofs to long indexing exercises with covers and finite subcovers...