# Exercise 2(d), Section 27 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, compactness, alternative-proof

> Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$; let $A \subset X$ be nonempty.
>
> (d) Assume that $A$ is compact; let $U$ be an open set containing $A$. Show that some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ is contained in $U$.

**My attempt:**

**Approach(1):** Since $U\in \mathcal{T}_d$ and $A\subseteq U$, we have $\forall a\in A, \exists r_a \gt 0$ such that $B_d(a, r_a) \subseteq U$. $B=\{ B_d(a, r_a)| a\in A\}$ is an open cover of $A$. $A$ is compact. By lemma 27.5, $\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $E\subseteq X$ and diam $(E) \lt \delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $E\subseteq B_d(x, r_x)$, for some $x\in A$. Take $\epsilon =\frac{\delta}{4}$. By exercise 2(c) section 27, $U(A,\epsilon)=\bigcup_{a\in A} B_d(a, \epsilon)$. Let $x,y\in B_d(a, \epsilon)$; $a\in A$. Then $d(x,y)\leq d(x,a)+d(a,y)\lt 2\epsilon =\delta /2$. So diam$(B_d(a, \epsilon))\leq \delta /2 \lt \delta$. Thus $B_d(a, \epsilon)\subseteq B_d(z, r_z)\subseteq \bigcup_{a\in A} B_d(a, r_a)$, for some $z\in A$. Hence $ U(A,\epsilon)=\bigcup_{a\in A} B_d(a, \epsilon)\subseteq \bigcup_{a\in A} B_d(a, r_a)\subseteq U$. Our desired result. **Is this proof correct?** Did I precisely use lemma 27.5?

**Approach(2):** [Prob. 2 (d), Sec. 27, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: If $A$ is compact and $U$ is an open set containing $A$, then . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2939244/861687).

**Approach(3):** https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939391/861687.

Comment: What you have written is incorrect, so one can deduce that you haven't used the lemma correctly. Note that your $r_x$ is fixed for every $x$. You are essentially saying that any set in $X$ that is sufficiently small lies very close to the compact set $A$. This can't possibly be correct. Take for example $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=[0, 1]$, $U=(-0.1, 1.1).$ Take any small set $E$ with diameter $\delta>0$ such that $E\subseteq [10, \infty).$ No matter how small $\delta$ is, you can not have $E\subseteq B_{d}(x, r_x)$ for some $x\in A=[0, 1].$

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the Lemma 27.5 must be the Lebesgue number lemma. Here is the Lebesgue number lemma (wording might be slightly different from Munkres's book. I don't have a copy with me right now.)

**Lebesgue Number Lemma** *Let $(Y, d)$ be a compact metric space and let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $(Y, d)$. Then, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $E\subseteq X$ such that $diam(E)<\delta$, there exists a set $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $E\subseteq U.$*

If you want to use it exactly like this, you will need to modify your argument a little. The metric space $(X, d)$ is not necessarily compact. But we have a compact set $A\subseteq X$. It can obviously be thought of as a compact metric space in its own right. But the covering $\{B_d(a, r_a): a\in A\}$ is not a cover of $A$ in $(A, d)$  (Why?). To remedy the situation, you can consider a modified cover, say, $\mathcal{C}:=\{B_d(a_i, r_{a_i})\cap A: a_i\}$ where $\{a_i\}$ is a finite collection of elements from $A$  such that $A\subseteq \cup_i B_d(a_i, r_{a_i}/4)$.

Now you can apply *Lebesgue Number Lemma* to this covering. This yields a $\delta>0$ such that every $E\subseteq A$ with diameter less than $\delta$ will be contained in $B_d(a_i, r_{a_i}/4)\cap A\subseteq B_d(a_i, r_{a_i}/4)$ for some $i$. Take $\epsilon<\min\{\delta, r_{a_i}\}/4$ (may not be necessary) and claim that $\epsilon$ works for you. That is, take any $x\in A$ and consider the set $E=B_d(x, \epsilon)$. You need to show that $E\subseteq \cup B_d(a_i, r_{a_i}).$

To this end, note that $E\cap A$ has diameter less than $\delta$ and hence by Lebesgue number lemma we know that $E\cap A\subseteq B_d(a, r_a/4)\cap A$ for some $a\in A.$ Now take any $z\in E$ and note that $d(a, z)\leq d(z, y)+d(y, a)$ for some $y\in E\cap A$. It follows that $d(a, z)\leq \epsilon+r_{a}/4\leq r_a/2.$ In particular, $E\subseteq B(a, r_a).$

Comment: So you’re saying Lebesgue Number Lemma don’t hold for compact subset of $X$($X$ is not compact). I’m sorry, I find your solution little bit vague(it is my fault), especially last paragraph, if you want to show $B_d (x,\epsilon )\subseteq B(a,r_a)$ using $d(a,z) \leq …$ argument then it’s very similar to approach(2), I guess.

Comment: Well, Lebesgue number lemma does hold for compact subsets of $X.$ What I am saying is that one needs to be careful with what kind of Lebesgue number lemma one has at one's disposal. The result that you are trying to prove is essentially the Lebesgue number lemma for compact subsets of a metric space. But as far as I remember Munkres gives Lebesgue number lemma for compact metric space itself. Therefore, this (general) version becomes an exercise.

Comment: As far the solution. I will try to expand on it a little more but it may take a few days.